# removing item from multidimensional array using attribute

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display an array of data produced from an sql query. this works fine. However I now wish not to display 1 item where the id attribute = a value.
code:

```
<?php foreach($sheet_list as $key => $sheet) : ?> 
        <?php if($sheet['id'] == $selected1){unset ($sheet_list[$key]);}?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$sheet['title'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('d F Y', strtotime($sheet['startDate'])); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('d F Y', strtotime($sheet['endDate'])); ?></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="selected2" id="selected2" value="<?=$sheet['id'];?>" <?php 
            if ($key == 0) echo ' checked ';
            ?>/></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

so this is producing a table which is fine, however it is in the foreach loop where i want NOT to display 1 array item and all its attributes where the "id" field is = to the variable `$selected1`
I have seen lots of questions posted here, however many for 1 or two dimensional arrays.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you should be using `continue;` instead of `unset()`:

```
<?php if($sheet['id'] == $selected1){ continue; } ?>
```

[`continue`<sup>PHP Docs</sup>](https://www.php.net/continue) makes the loop skip to the next iteration, effectively skipping the current iteration, which is what you want to do.

The benefit here is that you never modify for you `$sheet_list` array, unlike with `unset()` where you'll remove that item from the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to unset `$sheet_list[$selected1]` why don't you just do it before you enter the loop?

If you just want to skip output for this item, then use continue as suggested by nickb.